# how to retrieve data based from foreign key in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel

I have a problem with retrieving data from the foreign key.

This is my route for retrieving data:

```
Route::get('retrieve',function() {
    $tourism = \App\Models\Ratings::orderBy('rating','desc')->take(6)->get();

    return $tourism;
});
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
    var URL = '{{URL::to('/retrieve')}}';
    var htmlURL = '{{URL::to('/tourismplace/id/')}}';
    $.get(URL).success(function(data){
        var jumlahData = data.length;
        for(var i=0;i<jumlahData;i++){
            lokasi.push({
                lat : data[i].tourism.latitude,
                lon : data[i].tourism.longitude,
                zoom : 18,
                title : data[i].tourism[i].nama,
                html : "<a href='"+htmlURL+"/"+data[i].tourism.id +"'>"+data[i].tourism.nama+"</a>",
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png', // custom icon
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP

            });
        }
    }
```

`data[i].tourism.nama` means nama is in another table which is tourism table
and I already made the connection between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$tourism = \App\Models\Ratings::orderBy('rating','desc')->with('tourism')->take(6)->get();
```